# How to deal with missing values in KNN?

Tags: r, multiple-comparisons, model, k-nearest-neighbour, model-comparison

I have to deal with missing value in my dataset. I have a dataset of 10.000 obs. For the aim of my analysis, I need to run out the knn algorithm from CLASS package. 
I show you below the code:

```
buddy <- read.csv(file.choose(), header = TRUE , sep = ';')
attach(buddy)
fix(buddy)
train  <- dati[1:5000,]
test <- dati[5001: 10001, ]
test_labels <- dati[5001: 10001, ]
model4 <-knn(train = train, test= test, cl= test_labels, k=10, prob= TRUE) #no missing value are allowed ##
```

The last code doesn't work because of missing values. Can you help me? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious thing that you can do is drop examples with NAs or drop columns with NAs. Of course whether it makes sense to do this will depend on the situation.

There are some approaches that are covered by missing value [imputation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imputation_(statistics)) concept - imputing using column mean, median, zero etc. I'm not really familiar with R, but googling suggests that there are a lot of packages for this.

Other method which seems to be less standard is to use PCA-like technique (something based on matrix decomposition). For example [Generalized Low Rank Models](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/glrm.pdf) (GLRM) is a family that can be used for this. [This tutorial](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/glrm/glrm-tutorial.md) shows how to perform missing data imputation using H2O GLRMs in R.

Answer (score 0):

A solution may be to use only complete cases, for example:

```
model4 <- knn(train = train[complete.cases(train), ], test = test[complete.cases(test), ], cl = test_labels, k=10, prob= TRUE)
```

Comment: What exactly is the error message? And what are your "test_labels"? It looks like a dataframe (actually it seems to be the same dataframe as test) but it should be a factor, right?

Comment: Yes, but I follow an advice. I shouldn't have done it. What class should I insert? Anyway, the error is: Error in knn(train = train[complete.cases(train), ], test = test[complete.cases(test),  : 
  'train' and 'class' have different lengths

Comment: You said you have 10000 observations, have you triedtrain  <- dati[1:5000,]
test <- dati[5001: 10001, ]
t

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake, have you tried test <- dati[5001:10000, ] (instead of 10001)?

Comment: For cl, I guess that should be a factor with 10 levels (as you have k = 10 neighbours specified)

Comment: Oh yes I have tried it! Anyway, I transform my dependent variable in factor, next I split the dataset